# Facebook Graph API call successfully returns my user information, but not my albums?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The question is: is it my brain?  Or Facebook's infuriating API?

**Intention**:
Return my facebook album information and my user information

**result:** empty data set for album information, full result's for user information

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}


<?php
/****************************************************************************
Application settings
****************************************************************************/
$app_id = '123456';
$app_secret = "4543163864";
$my_url = "http://www.myurl.com/app";
$canvas_page = 'http://apps.facebook.com/my_canvas_page/';

# authorize the user using oauth protocol (including required permissions)
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope=user_photos,friends_photos";

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
     $fb_user_session = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

    # if authorization failed, kick back to auth_url
    if (empty($fb_user_session["user_id"])) 
    {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
    } 
    else 
    {
        /****************************************************************************
        User successfully logged in.
        ****************************************************************************/
        $my_albums = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=".$fb_user_session['oauth_token'];
        $my_info = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$fb_user_session['oauth_token'];



        echo "<a href='$my_albums'>my album information</a><br>";
        echo "<a href='$my_info'>my user information</a>";

        ### ignore this, just testing iframe call ###
        exit;
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $my_albums . "'</script>");
    } 
?>
```

**Additional information:**
Testing an 'album' request from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ while logged in works!  It successfully returns all my album info.  But I noticed the authorization token in the test URL is different from my retrieved application token ($fb_user_session['oauth_token']).  What is going on here?

Am I missing some kind of authorization step?  Why would my application return empty data for my albums using the exact same call & token while Facebook's test call returns a full set?  If anyone can help solve this problem once and for all, that would be awesome.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "user_photo_video_tags" to the list of scopes requested. Also, try calling the permissions api call to make sure you have access to the user's photos by checking the "user_photos" permission.
The url is:  https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=...